# Batch file: filepath manipulation

Tags: string, batch-file

I am trying to create a little script to convert video on windows using the 'send to' menu.
For this I want to create a new file name from the one in input.
But I fail to concatenate strings.

Following the syntax [found here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.StringConcatenation), I wrote this piece of code:

```
@echo Input:
@echo %1
set "outputfile=%1%.MP4"
@echo %outputfile%
```

But I have an issue with the quotes in the outputfile:

```
Input:
"D:\this is a test\MVI_7754.AVI"

D:\this is a test>set "outputfile="D:\this is a test\MVI_7754.AVI".MP4"
"D:\this is a test\MVI_7754.AVI".MP4
```

I would expect the extension inside the quotes not outside!

Could someone tell me how I can concatenate the file name and the extension?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo Input:
@echo %1
set outputfile="%~1.MP4"
@echo %outputfile%
```

to remove previous extension
use

```
set outputfile="%~n1.MP4"
```

if you don't use path names or

```
set outputfile="%~dpn1.MP4"
```

(name will be converted to full path)

Comment: BTW, is there is simple way to change the extension of the input file. The best solution for me would be to have in `outputfile` the string composed of the filename of `%1` without its original extension. Thanks!

Comment: corrected my answer to accomodate that. also, the first variant should be much simpler.

Comment: Thank you again! I took the last one since I need the path. I am used to Unix shells and I wouldn't expect Dos to be so different. Indeed with the first command you gave me `set "outputfile=%fname:"=%.MP4"`, I needed to pass the variable to VLC between "". With the last `set outputfile="%~dpn1.MP4"` I don't need them. I don't want to bother you too much, but if you could point me a website describing this kind of syntax, I would be eager to learn fishing ;)!

Comment: You don't need a website, you need `help set` and `help for` commands.

Comment: I just had a look at the documentation and as you said that's what I was missing. This will be very helpful in the future. Thanks!